# Generating forms and handling submit properly with Ember.js rc1

Tags: ember.js

I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly populate and accept an update from an Ember form under RC1. I've boiled it down to the bare essentials [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayoung/L9HMm/). I've made it far enough to display the form for a particular entity (user with first and last name) and the current values populate in the fields. However, as the user types, the fields actually update with each keystroke, and clicking the back button reveals that the data has already been changed without clicking the update button. I'd prefer to keep some logic in between the updates and only confirm an update after the user clicks the update button.

```
{{#view App.PersonFormView}}
  First name: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="firstName"}}
  Last name: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="lastName"}}
  <button {{action "updatePerson"}}>Update</button>
{{/view}}
```

In the form template, I was trying to follow one of the Ember.js examples, but doing so resulted in a long delay and a monstrous deprecation warning using RC1. I think the examples are still being updated. I'd prefer a more handlebars-elegant way of coding the form if it existed.

The second problem is that I cannot capture the submit event itself, either on the form view or the controller. I don't know where this event is going.

```
App.PersonFormController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  updatePerson: function(params){
    // this doesn't get triggered as I would have expected
    console.log('controller updatePerson: '+params);
  }
});
App.PersonFormView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'form',
  updatePerson: function(params){
    // this doesn't get triggered either!
    console.log('updatePerson params: '+params);
  }
});
```

In summary, I need to:

- populate the input fields with the values without having them linked directly back to the model's data while the user is typing
- catch the submit button's (or other control would be fine) clicked event along with the fields - and the entity's id - so that I can set them back on the model's data manually

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several things:

> > I cannot capture the submit event itself

Events are fired in the controller and the route, not the view.  The reason why your controller `PersonFormController` wasn't catching the event, is because the name is wrong.  The controller should be named after the route: `EditPersonController`.

It's generally good to pass the model along with the action:

```
<button {{action "updatePerson" content}}>Update</button>
```

Here is an updated version that catches the event: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyzeenny/L9HMm/5/

> > populate the input fields with the values without having them linked directly back to the model's data

It's generally good practice to bind the fields directly to the model, to avoid code duplication.

Your problem is not that the fields are bound directly to the model, it's that you have no control over what is happening (saved, not saved, left the route...)

To have solid control, it's best to put your updating logic in your route.  That way you can act accordingly when the user enters/leaves the route.

To catch your events in the route:

```
App.EditPersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
        updatePerson: function(record) {
          record.one('didUpdate', this, function() {
            this.transitionTo('index');
          });
          record.get('transaction').commit();
        }
    }
});
```

To rollback changes if the user doesn't click on `Update`, use the `deactivate` callback in the route:

```
App.EditPersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    deactivate: function() {
      this.modelFor('editPerson').get('transaction').rollback();
    },
    events: {
        updatePerson: function(record) {
          record.one('didUpdate', this, function() {
            this.transitionTo('index');
          });
          record.get('transaction').commit();
        }
    }
});
```

Now these won't work in the fiddle since you are not using ember-data models.

Comment: Excellent guidance, thank you. I don't want to touch ember data yet - maybe in a few months if it stabilizes. The RC1 ember API changes have been jarring enough. I did find a way to copy the attributes to another location so that they can be restored in the case of a cancel, so I think that will work for now.